# What does "dominoes" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, american-english

> "It's as if once you make a significant error, you cant help but make
>   a zillion others, like dominoes falling over in succession."

This line is from a novel called "Desperate in Dubai".

Comment: [Domino (tiles)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominoes)

Answer (score 7):

It stems from the practice of putting [dominoe tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominoes) up in rows and letting them fall over in a chain reaction, each tile tipping over one or more other stones when falling.

It also is the root of the expression [domino effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_effect) for a chain reaction in general.

Answer (score 4):

Dominos falling on top of each other
[image: here]